# From latex math formula to big jpeg file

Tags: math, latex, jpeg

I am wondering whether anyone knows a easy way to convert a latex math formula to a big jpeg file?

Here is the latex math formula:

```
\[
\lim_{u\rightarrow 0_+} \int_0^u \ud s \int_{-\infty}^\infty
\frac{f(u-s,x-y)}{\sqrt{2\pi
s}} \exp\left\{-\frac{y^2}{2s}\right\} \ud y
\]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why JPG? PNG is probably more suitable.

Comment: You should never use JPG with computer graphics. JPG is made for pictures and blurs them a little. PNG is lossles and does no harm to sharp borders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn’t really programming related at all, but here’s a way to do this:

- Use the class `standalone` in your LaTeX source file. This will produce a document that is exactly as large as needed, and no larger.
- Produce a PDF file using `pdflatex` …
- Convert to JPEG using `convert` (from ImageMagick).

Minimal example:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\begin{document}
\[
\sum_{i=1}^n i
\]
\end{document}
```

`convert` with appropriate resolution:

```
convert -density 400 file.pdf -scale 2000x1000 file.jpg
```

Caveat: `standalone` has some issues determining the size of the document. I don’t actually like the results it produces. You may require loading the `geometry` package and setting the document dimensions manually. This requires a bit of fiddling but the results are much better.

Comment: Very nice! Maybe we can even create a `bash` script to handle it all!

Comment: Actually, I can produce a pdf file without any margin by using empty class and epstool. What makes it work is the option -density in the command convert. I have looked that for some while.  Thanks a lot to Konrad.

Comment: Sorry, in previous comment, i mean I am using \documentclass{minimal}.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [eq2png](http://www-users.math.umd.edu/~olsson/eq2png/), a little Perl script that converts .tex to .png.

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting. I have downloaded it and will try. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Or you can make your life much easier and visit the website:

http://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php?lang=en-en

which outputs equations in many image formats.

Answer (score 1):

You might also use the precious **WolframAlpha**.
try for example

```
http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sin+x^2++cos+x^2+%3D+0.3
```

that gives you

[image]

along with plots, solutions and whatnot

Answer (score 1):

If you are on OS X you can use LaTeXit, part of the TeX live distribution and, I believe, separately downloadable.