# How to store mathematical expressions/explanations into database

Tags: database, math, database-design, web

I am given a task to develop a website for maths students with questions and their explanations.The site will have around 20,000 questions.And I need an effective way(easy storage,faster querying and fast rendering) to store those questions into the database.

Sample Question

In the first 10 overs of a cricket game, the run rate was only 3.2. What should be the run rate in the remaining 40 overs to reach the target of 282 runs?

```
Required run rate = 282 - (3.2 x 10)        =   250        = 6.25
                    ----------------           -----
                           40                    40
```

Questions is a simple string and can easily be stored.But the real problem is to store those expressions with brackets and divide into the database?

Comment: Nothing to do with HTML or CSS..

Comment: Perhaps investigate MathML.

Answer (score 3):

You could store the expressions in LaTeX in the database.

Edit:

You can use libraries like http://www.mathjax.org/ for client-side rendering of the equations.

Comment: And check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3716140/from-latex-math-formula-to-big-jpeg-file for how to convert the latex expressions to png for display on your web site. Maybe cache the images in a blob in the database for faster display.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to store a string representation of mathematical expressions: [MathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathML), [LaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) or [ASCIIMathML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCIIMathML).

For displaying it in a web browser I recommend [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).