# Django: How to store mathematical expressions in mysql and then use them

Tags: django

I am using Django and want users to be able to store mathematical expressions like the following in a mysql database following the BODMAS rule:

(A / B) * C + D / (E - D) + J^2

Then I want to be able to use these expressions later on in my views. Much like MS Excel.

I could build some models that stores as their objects, the variables and operators and build a function to implement BODMAS but it sounds like a lot of complication for a simple task.

Is there a simpler, shorter way to do both these steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of ways you can do this. You can save it as plain text, create separate table for each expression and use those when you're doing any sort of mathematical calculations.

What I did a few months back is save the entire expressions as rich text.

So I saved it like this:
Expression 1: (A / B) * C + D / (E - D) + J^2

Expression 2: (A / B) * C + D * (E + D) + J^2
Etc etc

My project was pretty simple which required me to save entire expressions in one line for quiz purposes.

You can use tinymce as rich text editor.

Another way is to save it as LaTeX. Look here for more details:

[How to store mathematical expressions/explanations into database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20652864/how-to-store-mathematical-expressions-explanations-into-database)

[MathJax for client side equation rendering](https://www.mathjax.org/)

Comment: Storing the expression is half the problem. It would be useful only if it can be used in my views. Any idea about how I can use it in views? By substituting the variables with numbers. Without having to develop a complicated function?

Comment: @mad_accountant you'll have to handle the substitution on the front end. So if a user inputs x = 5 you'll have to take the value of x and calculate using javascript/typescript and then store the answer in database if you want. 
On the other hand you can store each variable independently in database and use them for calculation. I've updated my answer and provided mathJax link